# Mongoose 'required' validator is not working

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm trying to validate request body against mongoose model with 'required' validator but so far has not been able to achieve the desired results. I'm using next.js api routes with connection to MongoDB to handle requests.

Here's my model:

```ts
import { Document, Model, Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

export interface ISimpleProject extends Document {
    title: string;
    headline: string;
    summary: string;
    img?: string;
    github?: string;
    url?: string;
}

const SimpleProjectSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    headline: { type: String, required: true },
    summary: { type: String, required: true },
    img: { type: String },
    github: { type: String },
    url: { type: String },
});

export const SimpleProject: Model<ISimpleProject> =
    models.SimpleProject || model("SimpleProject", SimpleProjectSchema);
```

And here's the request handler:

```ts
export default handleMethods()
    .method<ModelWithID<ISimpleProject>>('POST', async (req, res) => {
        await connectToMongoDB();

        const body: ISimpleProject = req.body;

        const newSimpleProject = new SimpleProject(body);

        return newSimpleProject
            .save()
            .then((result) => {
                res.status(200).json({ result: true, data: result });
            })
            .catch((e) => errorHandler(e, res));
    })
    .prepare();
}
```

For example, if I want to send a POST request with the following body:

```json
{
    "title": "Hello World!"
}
```

I expect to get an error from this request because fields `headline` and `summary` are not present. Instead I get back the saved document in response, as if there is no validation errors.

Comment: Did you try removing the `models.SimpleProject ||` part?

Comment: @MaartenDev yes, I tried to remove it but in that case I would be getting error - OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `SimpleProject` model once compiled

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how and why but upgrading mongoose from `6.2.5` to `6.2.9` seems to resolve the issue.

`yarn remove mongoose` and `yarn add mongoose` to install the latest version.

Now validation kicks in and everything works as expected. Make sure to restart your dev server as well.

My guess is that old model got cached (I don't know if that's current behaviour in mongoose), so when I restarted the server everything worked fine.